# Testing Firebase Deep Linking For Install Path

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I've integrated Firebase into my application in the following methods

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
             openURL:(NSURL *)URL
             options:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)options

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
    continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
      restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))restorationHandler
```

I'm able to successfully test a link from mobile Safari that launches the iOS application in the Simulator.

My question is, is there a way to test the path for following a mobile link that launches the app store and then continues passing the link to the iOS application?

I want to be able to test my changes in the simulator before submitting the code to the App Store.

Answer (score 4):

Firebase doesn't know (or care) how the application is installed onto your device. Installing directly from Xcode and using a beta distribution system (TestFlight, Hockey, Fabric, etc.) are treated exactly the same way as going through the App Store.

Here is a flow you can use to test this:

1. Install a build of your app that includes the Firebase Dynamic Links SDK
2. Generate a link and post it somewhere
3. Uninstall your app
4. Open the link and let it redirect all the way through to the App Store page
5. Close the App Store
6. Install a build of your app locally (using either Xcode or TestFlight/Fabric/etc.)
7. Open your app
8. The link path will be returned to you, the same way it would be when your app is installed from the App Store by a user.

Comment: Are you sure that step 8 works as expected? We are having problems getting the dynamic link path after the app is installed.

Comment: @DennisBurford in my testing it always has! Feel free to post a new question with snippets from your AppDelegate, since I suspect any issue would be there.

Comment: @DennisBurford did you ever fix this?

Comment: It seems that Firebase just copies a link containing the deep link into the clipboard. That's probably why it works even if you install the app from another source afterward.